# Disabling MySQL Concurrency

Tags: php, mysql, concurrency

Does the following code really disable concurrent execution?

```
LOCK TABLES codes WRITE;
INSERT INTO codes VALUES ();
SELECT mid FROM codes ORDER BY expired DESC LIMIT 0,1;
UNLOCK TABLES;
```

The PHP will execute SQL. The PHP file will be requested by many users via HTTP. Would it really execute in isolation for every users?

*mid* is something which has to be unique for every user so I think I should use MySQL locks to achieve that.

Comment: Lock isolation is ensured on per-connection basis. While one connection has acquired an exclusive lock on a table, any other connection acquiring a lock on the table will block. It does not matter if other connections authenticate as the same user or a different user. Your approach is not correct and you should look into autoincrement fields and unique constraints.

Comment: Thanks. With that definition, don't you think I'm good? User requests php file, php file will connect to mysql and execute query with lock but if in the mean time some other user requests the same file, php will try to make the connection to mysql and when it will try to execute the same query, it won't succeed because the table is in locked state. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, with regard to the locking semantics, you're good. You are just trying to achieve something relatively simple in an overly complicated way.

Comment: You seem to have simple alternative. Please write me that as an answer.

Comment: @dystroy has already provided you with a simple alternative, that's why I haven't posted a full answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a table with an auto incremented key and you use mysql_insert_id just after insertion, it is guaranteed to be unique and it won't mix user threads (it fetches the ID on the connection you give). No need to lock the table.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php

Comment: PHP connects via same mysql user credentials for every web user request. So where's the isolation? Is it there at the web user level or mysql user level?

Comment: Usually you make a connection for each php request. The fact they share the same user is irrelevant.